# Does c# uses the "Digit grouping symbol" to represent, read or write any value?

Tags: c#, number-formatting

Like many of you I've had trouble with region settings.

I've solved all the problems so far using:

```
string str = Convert.ToString(9999.9);
```

and

```
double.TryParse(textBox378.Text.Replace(",", sepdec.ToString()).Replace(".", sepdec.ToString()), out num);
```

Where `sepdec` is my decimal separator.

However I've noticed that some countries use a decimal separator, and a Digit grouping symbol, wich is a separator for thousands.

For example, 9999.9 in some countries should be 9,999.9 where `.` is a decimal separator.

I've tried several examples, but it none my program would use a "Digit grouping symbol" to represent, read, or write any value. In this case I'm correct, but as I'm not an expert on this matter, I'd like someone experienced to comment or answer the question.

Does c# ever uses the "Digit grouping symbol" ?

Comment: When you say "read or write" are you storing your data to a text file? Or are you reading data from a textbox from the user?

Comment: I'm using both, sometimes I read a value from a textbox, others from a datatable. But in both cases I used Convert.ToString(), and from some tests  I've made, it never failed, and always used the decimal separator only.

Comment: Look at @soner-gonul answer below.  You have to use [IFormatterProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

All representations of a numerical value depends on culture settings that you used. If you don't use any [`IFormatProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx), representation will be based on your [`CurrentCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) settings.

The mentioned characters are keeped on any culture as [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator.aspx) and [`NumberGroupSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numbergroupseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) properties.

By the way, replacing your `,` to `.` is a bad idea when you parse your `string` to `double` because your string *may* have already `.` as a thousands separator.

You have 2 options in such a case. First you can use a culture that have `.` as a `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `,` as a `NumberGroupSeparator` like `InvariantCulture`;

```
string s = "9999.9";
var d = double.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or you can use [`CultureInfo.Clone()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to copy your `CurrentCulture` and set it's `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator` properties manually like;

```
string s = "9999.9";
CultureInfo c = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
c.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
c.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
var d = double.Parse(s, c);
```

Comment: That's exactly my doubt :) But I've tested a few different cultures and my code never failed. It never used the thousands separator even with big numbers. I've used 9999 to test it.

Comment: @ng80092b Updated my answer. Are you sure your cultures have the different `NumberDecimalSeparator` and `NumberGroupSeparator` properties? I don't think so :) Also as I mentioned in my answer, you can `Clone` your current culture and set these properties. For example; clone your current culture and these properties with `+` and `%` characters, I certainly sure your code will fail :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

You're missing some points on parsing/formatting here.

First, [`double.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx) method accept `IFormatProvider` parameter, with this you can instruct the Parser to follow a different a standard/pattern and so do not need to replace "," by "." or any other handling. If you know the source culture do the following:

```
var strValue = "1.000,00"; ////in brazil, decimal separator is comma, and grouping is dot
var brazilianCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR");
var value = double.Parse(strValue, brazilianCulture);
 //value == 1000
```

You can use `IFormatProviders` to also format your strings from double values, there is [`double.ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/d8ztz0sa(v=vs.110).aspx) method for that too:

```
var usaCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
var usStrValue = value.ToString("0,000.00", usaCulture); //1,000.00
var brStrValue = value.ToString("0,000.00", brazilianCulture ); //1.000,00
```

When using `ToString` your format parameter must always follow US standard, .NET will work to replace digits grouping and decimal separator to the correct output culture.

Check working in https://dotnetfiddle.net/CxKfgW

Comment: The problem is exactly that, I don't know the source culture. It might be any of the hundreds available in regional options.

Comment: Your users should have a culture setting in their profile from which you would take that, you cannot simply discover what is the culture, there are cases where multiple culture can be successfully applied to a string value with different results. That's is how everything works...or you let them choose one or do you enforce one

Comment: you may also infer from browser settings, http header or other method, but the point is your app should know what culture is expected.

Comment: I've just tried using `MessageBox.Show((9999).ToString());` and the digit grouping symbol doesn't appear.

Comment: [without parameter, you use the "G" format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is simply ["The most compact of either fixed-point or scientific notation."](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx), if you want complex formats you should use the overloads whith take format strings as parameter, MSDN has a lot of docs about parsing and formating which can help you

Comment: can you point out some examples where the digit grouping symbol will actually make a difference?  Because  value.ToString isn't showing it.

Comment: "1,000" is 1000 in Brazil, but only 1 in USA.

Comment: What if I only allow the decimal separator in textBoxes? :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will use it when you format strings using the N format. 12345.ToString("N") = "12,345"

Can you explain what you're trying to do exactly? Looking at your code it seems to be a very inefficient way to be handling globalization. What is your goal? Perhaps we can help provide a better solution.

I believe what you want is:

```
double.TryParse("12,345", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out num);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw(v=vs.110).aspx for more information.

Comment: I was trying to make my program compatible with comma `,` and  dot `.` decimal separators, But since i got here, I'd rather learn something about the subject and improve. But never in my code I use XXXX.ToString, I have always used Convert.ToString(XXXX);

Comment: Will you know the region setting ahead of time? Meaning, is it some application that might be on a computer in China and when there needs to support Chinese formats, but in the US it supports US formats? Or are you trying to build something that supports any numeric format at the same time? I'm no expert, but there are other things other than just comma and period. Some cultures use spaces as a thousands grouping, for example, and  I couldn't tell you if those 3 cover the entire world. If you know the culture ahead of time, we can load the culture object and let .NET handle the heavy lifting.

Comment: I couldn't know the culture ahead. I could use a region selector during install. But that would go very ahead of the program intent. Can't c# identify the current culture?

Comment: It knows the culture of the PC. But my question is, I have a PC with US settings. Do you need me to be able to enter a Chinese formatted number, or just a US formatted number? Whereas the guy in China just needs Chinese formats, or any format as well?

Comment: No, I don't need that. I only need the US guy to use his number format, as the German guy to use his number format (in german comma is used as decimal separator)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not an answer to the question but you have to be asking this for a reason so: If you know that for example the number that the user has supplied must be a decimal number with 2 digits after the decimal "point" or if you can enforce that on the UI and you want to be completely sure you have the right number, you can do this:

```
var strNum = "9,999.56".Replace(",", "").Replace(".", "");
double d = Convert.ToDouble(strNum) / 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use from below short line for getting your digit grouping symbol, and use that in the other part of your code.

```
string DigitGroupingSymbol = (9.99F).ToString().Replace("9","");
```